# CSS: Placing an arrow / triangle with border on the top of my drop down menu

Tags: css, css-shapes

Just launched this website (http://dovidoved.org/) and the client wants one of those triangles / arrows on the top of each drop down menu. Problem is the menu has a border around it and the arrow should mesh with both the background as well as the border. Not sure how to do that. Any suggestions? Must I have to use an image? Here's my CSS:

```
 /* creates triangle */
 .main-navigation ul ul:before {
     border-bottom: 10px solid #fae0bb;
     border-left: 10px solid transparent;
     border-right: 10px solid transparent;
     content: "";
     height: 0;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: -10px;
     width: 0;
 }

 .main-navigation ul ul {
     background: #fae0bb;
     border: 8px solid #fffefe;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0;
     top: 2.8em;
     left: -999em;
     width: 200px;
     z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: What's a problem to a add a css triangle to .nav-menu a:after?

Comment: You could use both an image as background of each link, positioned in right side, or maybe an icon-font (that is more versatile and flexible, allowing you to change size and color without problem.). In this second case, I suggest you [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/)

Comment: you can use `:after` pseudo element to add a border http://jsfiddle.net/ond3g1jp/

Comment: can you explain what you need, I don't understand " should mesh with both the background as well as the border". An image would be great.

Comment: you can use this, http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/caret-down/, this are icon-fonts so you can style them like text.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this using `:before`and `:after`pseudo elements, to create two triangles :

```
.main-navigation ul ul:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 11px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fae0bb transparent;
    z-index:9999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: -22px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 17px 17px 17px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
    z-index:9998;
}
```

You just have to set the correct `right` value for both to make them fit to what you need.

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/3byqw769/)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the example. Really worked out great.

Answer (score 2):

```
.main-navigation a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -20px;
}
```

[image]

Adjust the padding of `li` to make triangles fit.