# Show arrow pointer below li with different colour pointer on active li

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set up something that looks like this.
[image: What I want to achieve]

So far I can only get this.
[image: what I've got]

I built a list using

```
<ul id="etabs">
<li class="tab left"><a href="#newCarousel">New Arrivals</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="#popularCarousel">Featured Products</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="#offersCarousel">Offers</a></li>
</ul>
```

And styled it with

```
ul#etabs {list-style:none; max-width:100%; background-color:#fff; margin:0 auto; font-size:1.2em; height:61px; padding:0;}
ul#etabs li {float:left; width:33.3333%; position: relative;text-align: center;}
ul#etabs li a {display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; color:#000; padding:20px 0;}

ul#etabs li .active {background-color: #a6d120; position: relative;}
ul#etabs li a.active {color:#fff;}
```

I tried adding a background image to the li but I can only position it within the li itself, not below it. I did consider just applying a whole background image instead of trying to add the pointers, but it has to be able to resize as viewport is changed.
What is the best solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Placing an arrow / triangle with border on the top of my drop down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790831/css-placing-an-arrow-triangle-with-border-on-the-top-of-my-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the triangle shape by using borders on an empty pseudo element.

Here is a good explanation of how this techniques works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073558/746736

Or if you are feeling lazy, there are [online triangle generators](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/).

Adjust the figures to match your design.

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px 15px 0 15px;
border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
```

This can then be positioned below your `li`.

```css
ul#etabs {list-style:none; max-width:100%; background-color:#fff; margin:0 auto; font-size:1.2em; height:61px; padding:0;}
ul#etabs li {float:left; width:33.3333%; position: relative;text-align: center;}
ul#etabs li a {display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; color:#000; padding:20px 0;}

ul#etabs li.active {background-color: #a6d120; position: relative;}
ul#etabs li a.active {color:#fff;}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

ul#etabs li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 15px 0 15px;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -19px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
ul#etabs li.active:after {
  border-color: #a6d120 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul id="etabs">
  <li class="tab left active"><a href="#newCarousel">New Arrivals</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#popularCarousel">Featured Products</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#offersCarousel">Offers</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does just what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use Pseudo-elements to create the little arrow point.

This can be achieved by adding ::after or ::before attributes to your css element.

Take a look at this example: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp